# Is there a way to define a column as "updatable via trigger only" in order to enforce integrity?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, rdbms, data-integrity

I have a table called `customer_transactions` that contains a column named `amount` of type `DECIMAL` (not unsigned). In the `customer` table there is a column named `account_balance` which must always be equal to the sum of the customer's `customer_transactions.amount` rows.

Is there a way to enforce this equality by denying any other means of updating the `amount` column except via trigger (preferably a particularly named trigger)? Or maybe there's another way to enforce this that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to manage privileges on the server? I've never tried it, but I believe that in MySQL 5.1 and above, you could revoke any write privileges on the `customer.amount` column from your application's database user, while leaving the privilege to read the column and execute table triggers. Providing the user you use to create the trigger has permission to modify the `amount` column, less privileged users should then be able to still use the trigger.

Unless I have misunderstood the documentation... which is possible.

[MySQL 5.1 Create Trigger documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

Comment: Per-column privileges may be the simplest and most reliable way to handle this. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ArthurRied I'm curious - did this work out for you?

Comment: Actually, we never implemented this. After revisiting it we decided that having a summary balance column on the customer table wasn't a great idea and instead put a trigger-enforced `running_balance` column on the `customer_transactions` table.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create an effect like that.

If the `account_balance` column is `not null` and the application needs to insert rows, define a default value for the `account_balance` column.

Create a view that contains all the columns except `account_balance` and a *calculated* `account_balance` column:

```
create view customer_transactions_2 as -- call it whatever you want
select id, col1, col2, ..., account_balance + 0 as account_balance
from customer_transactions
```

Give your applications the view to work with. They will be able to do everything with the view that they can with the table, *except* update the `account_balance` value (you can't write to the database through views for non-raw columns).

Your trigger on the base table will be able to update the `account_balance` column.

Comment: So because there is a calculation, the view's column is now non-writeable (the `account_balance` column is actually in the `customer` table but I can just apply the technique there instead). That's a great tip.

Comment: FYI I don't have enough rep to upvote but once I do I will come back and do so.

Comment: Yes - raw columns (that are passed through from the base table as-is) are writeable, but manufactured ones are not, because the database doesn't cater for reversal of calculations to get the raw value from the generated one, and many times it's impossible to reverse, eg if the calculation was a substr for example.